# EV3 classroom cannot create New Project

Tags: ev3, mindstorms

- EV3 Classroom V1.5.0
- Windows 10

I run a lab of 24 laptops running EV3 Classroom v1.5.0. Over the last week, more and more computers are unable to create new projects and/or open existing projects files.

When creating a new project clicking on the "New Project" button causes the spinning wheel icon that doesn't move on to a new project created.  If attempting to load an existing project through "File>Open" the Windows menu disappears but no Open File dialog is created to select the file.

Any suggestions or additional data needed for help me?

Comment: Does it work if you upgrade to the latest version? v1.5.3 is the latest available for Windows from [here](https://education.lego.com/en-us/downloads/mindstorms-ev3/software#downloads) at the time this comment was written.

Comment: You could also try checking for recent Windows updates and try reverting those to see if that broke something.

Comment: Will do so @DavidLechner, my tech is offsite for the day but I'll try and get the IDE updated. Reverting windows updates isn't something we can do but I'll check and make sure those units don't have any updates pending.